# Is there a problem to put decimals of my new token fewer than 18?

Tags: tokens, erc-20

I know that it's possible put more or less decimals, but if I want, for example, 8 decimals, would my token works good as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will work just fine.

It's just typical to have 18 decimals, but nothing really stops you from using a different number. The decimals are only used for external integrations, so the only things that may break are external integrations. But also those should read the amount of decimals from the contract and not assume 18.

Answer (score 0):

[USDC](https://etherscan.io/token/0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48) uses 6 decimal places and it works perfectly fine.